# Redirect automatically from Woocommerce thankyou to an external link passing variables

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

In Woocommerce, after placing an order, I Would like to redirect customer automatically after 5 sec from the thankyou page to external link passing a few variables as the `order_id`, and the `order_ammount`.

So How can I redirect customer automatically from Woocommerce thankyou to an external link passing variables after 5 seconds?

Any track is welcome.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38059549/1117368) for a similar case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will redirect from checkout page to an external link passing few variables after 5 seconds using php and javascript:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'thankyou_delated_external_redirection', 10, 1 );
function thankyou_delated_external_redirection( $order_id ){
    if( ! $order_id ){
        return;
    }

    $order          = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Instannce of the WC_Order Object
    $order_total    = $order->get_total(); // Order total amount

    $link_redirect  = 'http://www.example.com/'; // Base url
    $link_redirect .= '?order_id='.$order_id.'&order_ammount='.$order_total; // passed variables

    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        // Redirect with a delay of 5 seconds
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = '<?php echo $link_redirect; ?>';
        }, 5000);
    });
    </script>
    <?php;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

> **The redirection link** is like `http://example.com/path/?order_id=1420&order_ammount=136.20`