# Woocommerce custom redirection based on purchased product after payment

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, orders

I am looking out to redirect user to specific pages which will vary from product to product. So, once user completes payment for Product A, he will be redirected to Link A , which is an external link.
If he buys Product B, he will be redirected to Product B.

If not, At least I want to display dynamic URL on checkout page based on the product, once user completes payment.

Any input for this functionality ?

I tried the Affiliate link/Virtual products in woo commerce but its a different thing ..

Answer (score 4):

I created a simple plugin using the code below to accomplish something similar...

/*
Plugin Name: Woocommerce Custom Thank You page per Product
Description: This plugin will allow you to set up a custom thank you page per product for woocommerce.
Author: Gabriel Collignon
*/

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'redirect_product_based', 1 ); 
function redirect_product_based ( $order_id ){
            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        
            foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                // Add whatever product id you want below here
                if ( $item['product_id'] == 181 ) {
                    // URL 
                     wp_redirect( 'https://www....' );
                } else {
                    // The other URL
                    wp_redirect( 'https://www....' );
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will redirect to specifics Url based on order item (product Id) once customer complete payment and order has 'processing' or 'completed' status:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'thankyou_custom_redirection', 10, 1 );
function thankyou_custom_redirection( $order_id ){
    global $wp;

    $order_id = get_query_var('order-received');

    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') && ! empty($order_id) && $order_id > 0 ){

        // Get the WC_Order Object instance
        $order = wc_get_order( absint($order_id) );
        
        // Allowed order statuses
        $order_statuses = array('processing', 'completed');
        
        if ( is_a($order, 'WC_Order') && in_array($order->get_status(), $order_statuses) ) {
            $settings = product_ids_for_links_settings(); // Load settings

            // Loop through order items
            foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                $product    = $item->get_product();
                $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
                print_pr($product_id);

                if( in_array( $product_id, array_keys($settings) ) ){
                    $link_redirect = esc_url($settings[$product_id]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if( isset($link_redirect) && ! empty($link_redirect) ) {
            // (optional) passing variables to URL
            $link_redirect .= '?order_id='.$order_id.'&product_id='.$product_id;

            // Redirection
            wp_redirect( $link_redirect );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Redirect automatically from Woocommerce thankyou to an external link passing variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172245/redirect-automatically-from-woocommerce-thankyou-to-an-external-link-passing-var/55173818#55173818)

Answer (score -2):

Your algoritm:

1. Get a ID product from your order.
2. Get permalink find product.
3. Used wp_redirect(permalink);